# How do I run only specific Rspec tests in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I only know the `rake spec` command which runs all the tests.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to run all your specs in your spec folder

```
rspec spec
```

If you want to run all the specs in your user_spec.rb

```
rspec spec/models/user_spec.rb
```

If you want to run one spec from user_spec.rb on line 29

```
rspec spec/models/user_spec.rb -l 29
```

If you want to run all specs tagged with mytag

```
rspec spec --tag mytag

  it "is not valid without a name", :mytag do
    user = Factory.build(:User, :name => nil)
    user.should_not be_valid
  end
```

If your using bundler you will need to use

```
bundle exec rspec
```

Comment: It seems test database will not get rolled back after using rspec. For example, if a user is created in a spec, it remains there next time rspec is executed.

Comment: Take a look at this gem https://github.com/bmabey/database_cleaner for cleaning database.